# Expected value of a variable that possibly decreases n times

Tags: expected-value

Assume I have a program that executes the following pseudocode

```
x = 1
for 0 to n
    y = random real in [0,1)
    if y < x
        x = y
return x
```

What is the expected value of the return of this function wrt to `n`?

In english, set `X` to 1000.  Choose a random real in the half-open interval [0,1) `n` times, setting the minimum to `X`.  What is the expected value of `X` in terms of `n`?

Comment: The duplicate addresses a slightly more complicated question, but all the answers tackle it by first answering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac1{n+1}$

[source](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2016/09/25/the-expectation-of-the-minimum-of-iid-uniform-random-variables/)

(your pseudo-code is ambiguous. this assumes that the for-loop executes $n$ times in total, i.e. that the maximum value is non-inclusive.)